# How to merge two text files?

Tags: file, input, textinput

I have a 200 MB text file. But, I need to test my program on bigger text files. Is it possible to merge two text files?
I can not open the file, to copy and paste it into another. I need different solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, merge two text files you can use cat command, like this:

```
cat a.txt b.txt >c.txt
```

If you have no permissions to open the file, get help from the administrator

Answer (score 4):

What programming language are you using? Because you could just read both text files into a program, then write each to an output stream and save as a file.

Otherwise, if it's DOS you're after, try

```
copy file1.ext+file2.ext target.ext
```

Comment: I am using C language and the text file is my input. Do I have to use thic command in DOS to make text file with different sizes?

Answer (score 1):

The copy command with + add an extra character at the end. The cat command is doing just fine.

Answer (score 0):

### You can simple use Python for this job, as below:

```
import shutil
import os
import glob

filenames = glob.glob('*.txt')

with open('output_file.txt','wb') as wfd:
    for f in filenames:
        with open(f,'rb') as fd:
            shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd)
```